# How to auto-play videos like in youtube app on flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-packages

I wanted to create a flutter app just like youtube, I want my app to have an infinite scrolling list of cards where by default the card will display an image. If the user stops scrolling, then only the first card in the viewport will start playing a video. The video should only play while the card is visible on the screen and should stop as soon as it moves out of the viewport.

For example:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/19HMdjrFl8ZbE5TEE3ekq62wMjNl0eWpU/view

I have no idea on which package I have to use. Will flutter youtube player work?

Comment: Did you try with [youtube_player_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/youtube_player_flutter)

Comment: @YeasinSheikh no i wanna know whether it will work or not

Answer (score 0):

Add a listview with a controller.  consider a card of height 200. Now if the controller offset is 800 play the video of that 800/200. Which is 4th one. You can use any video player package which has an option to statt and stop video

Comment: Thank you so much, I think I got what your saying but still I'm a bit confused with the code, I've never used offset before so can you share that part of the code?..It would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Hello check this package and try to test it to see if it is your solution.
https://pub.dev/packages/inview_notifier_list

Answer (score 0):

use `VisibilityDetector` to detect if the video is visible on the screen

```
 VisibilityDetector(
        key: 'your key',
        onVisibilityChanged: (visibility) {
          //if 80% of the video is visible on the screen
          if (visibility.visibleFraction > 0.0) {
            'play video';
          } else {
           'pause video';
          }
        },
        child: ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            topLeft: Radius.circular(5.0),
            bottomLeft: Radius.circular(5.0),
          ),
          child: VideoPlayer(videoPlayerController!),
        ),
      ),
```